# When I try to create animated objects from sprite on Android, they start to be slow

Tags: android, animation, bitmap, sprite

I use followed example ([described here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaOPq.png)) to animate my sprite sheet.

from example I wrote my Object:

```
public class Sprite {
private int x, y;
private int width, height;
private Bitmap b;
MainGamePanel ov;
int currentFrame = 0;

public Sprite(MainGamePanel mainGamePanel, Bitmap blob) {
    this.ov = mainGamePanel;
    this.b = blob;
    // 1x12
    height = b.getHeight();
    width = b.getWidth()/12;
    x = y = 50;     
}

private void update(int dist) {              
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % 12;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    //return _b;
}

public void draw(int shift, Canvas canvas, int dist) {
    update(dist);
    int srcX = currentFrame * width;
    Rect  src = new Rect(srcX, 0, srcX+width, height);
    Rect  dst = new Rect(x, y+shift, x+width, y+height+shift);
    canvas.drawBitmap(b, src, dst, null);
}
```

Here every 100 msec I take different part from image (Bitmap) and show it.

1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> ... -> 12

So my creature flies and moves with wings.

If I show only **1** object, it seems good but when I try to run 20 creatures in loop:

```
  Bitmap blob = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.sprite3);

  for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
      spriteList.add(new Sprite(this, blob));
  }


....

for(int i=0; i<spriteList.size(); i++){
  sprite = spriteList.get(0);
  sprite.draw(canvas, dist);
}
```

My objects start to be slow according to drawn object count.

It happens I think because of `Thread.sleep(100);`.

I don't see any performance problem.

Sounds like each object sleep pauses all objects.

For 20 objects this sleep grows to 2 sec.

For sure I use workaround like:

```
int sleep = 100/spriteList.size();
Thread.sleep(sleep);
```

But code looks messy.

Can anyone help me how to fix it?

Here is *sprite3* image: [image]

**[EDIT]**

Maybe I need create each object in separate Thread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not sleep while rendering; it greatly reduces the performance, especially, as you add new Animation Clips, etc.  Also, don't create objects within your onDraw method and do try to reuse the Rect objects. Creating objects during rendering is very expensive.

Comment: Ok, i understand your point about reusing `Rect` but i need shift on my sprite sheet somehow with delay of 100ms. How can I do that without sleep? Thanks

Comment: If you want to have tight control of when you should draw the next frame, I would suggest passing in the time in the update method and calculating whether you should draw and which frame to draw. The rule is to let the rendering go as fast as possible, but draw selectively.